# Can I develop Windows 10 App on a Windows 8.1 device?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-10

I would like to follow the guide (http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm) to develop a Windows 10 app, but it says it needs the Windows 10 Insider Preview as the requirements. However, I cannot download it right now as it states that:

> We’re very close to the public release of Windows 10 so we’re not onboarding any new PCs to the Windows Insider Program just now.

Can I now have any ways to develop a Windows 10 App? I want to finish making it so that it can be out once Windows 10 is released. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can develop Windows 10 apps with Windows 8.1,too. You need Visual Studio 2015 to and the latest Windows SDK. In the future you will be able to develop from Windows 7, too. (Both has been announced at the build conference in San Francisco.)

There will be some limitations - you can't deploy your Win10 app to your local system, as you are running W8.1 locally. (But you could use a remote or virtual machine).
There will also be some limitations around the XAML designer.
The easiest way is probably to start developing on a remote machine in the cloud. Here's a guide how to set things up: https://github.com/DanielMeixner/DevDreamMachine

As we are getting closer to release of VS2015 and W10, please check out this post, too. There are some limitations around app development between release of VS2015 and release of Windows which might affect you.
http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/29/release-dates-and-compatibility-visual-studio-2015-and-windows-10-sdk/

Comment: OK. I tried it and followed the steps to create my first Win10 App. I also installed the Win10 emulator, wanting to test and run the app on it. But once I click Run, the phone keeps showing the "loading" screen (with blue dots runniong above). The OS can be loaded though, just the app can't be loaded. Am I doing things right? Should the app supposed to be able to run on the emulator? Thanks!

Comment: well, I find it it actually works if I replace my URL wit another one. My page has a window.location= someLocation that is prevent is from working. Does the Win10 App browser not support it or something? But if I go to the browser on the simulator and open, it runs ok.

Comment: I haven't tried this but if you are redirecting with window.location this actually might not work. Make sure the new URI appears in the list of ApplicationContentUriRules in the appxmanifest.